# Use of carry flag for SBB RCX,RCX after subtraction

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am reading a book: [[xchg rax, rax]](http://www.xorpd.net/pages/xchg_rax/snip_03.html). The following is the 0x03 snippet of the book and I can't make sense out of this one.

```
sub      rdx,rax
sbb      rcx,rcx
and      rcx,rdx
add      rax,rcx
```

I have been working on this since a week now (couple of minutes everyday). I have studied about some things trying to solve it: signed representation of numbers, how subtraction works, role of CF after a subtraction. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965923/carry-overflow-subtraction-in-x86/8966863#8966863) answer and the list given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034566/overflow-and-carry-flags-on-z80/8037485#8037485). I don't see the point of checking CF after a subtraction, except in the cases of maybe overflows.

In what situations is checking the carry flag useful after a subtraction?

Comment: Overflows :)  Of course the code shown does not check CF as such. It uses CF to chain two 64 bit subtracts together to form a 128 bit subtraction (hence the name "carry").

Comment: Duplicate of [Best assembly or compilation for minimum of three values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306615/best-assembly-or-compilation-for-minimum-of-three-values). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18319810/902497) gives the above code fragment as the way to do a two-value min.

Comment: there are various cases that CF is set even if there was no overflow, for example [after BZHI](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BZHI.html), [COMIS\[SD\]](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/COMISS.html), or a shift/rotate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually that code is a clever branchless way to do `rax = min(rax, rdx)`.

```
sub rdx, rax ; rdx = rdx - rax; CF set if rdx < rax
sbb rcx, rcx ; rcx = all 1 bits if CF was set, 0 otherwise
and rcx, rdx ; rcx = rdx - rax if CF was set, 0 otherwise
add rax, rcx ; rax = rax + (rdx - rax) = rdx if CF was set, unchanged otherwise
```

A more readable branching version is:

```
cmp rdx, rax
jnc done ; if rdx - rax produced no carry, rax is smaller or equal
mov rax, rdx ; otherwise rdx is the smaller one
done:
```

It's still just using CF for overflow checking.

Comment: There's no advantage to the sub/sbb/and/add version over cmp/cmov, is there?  The sequence can't execute until both rdx and rax are ready, same as cmov, but it takes more uops.  `adc` and `sbb` are each as expensive as `cmov` (2 uops on Intel, so there's the same complex-decode bottleneck when not running from the uop cache).  Only AMD CPUs recognize `sbb` as depending only on flags, but that doesn't matter here since rdx and flags are both produced by the same instruction.  So anyway, **this should perform the same as `cmp/cmov` plus 2 other instructions on the critical path**.