# Finding the Max Value within 6 registers, Assembly X86

Tags: assembly, max, x86-64

I am trying to complete this function that takes in 6 registers and each registers holds a value, out of the 6 registers I am trying to output the greatest value and return it in the rax register. I have the layout of how I want my prolog and epilog to work and how I want it to return at the end but I am just stuck on creating the most efficient / bruteforce way to do this. I was trying to see if I could do it like in higher languages like python or c where I can push the registers into an array, sort the list and return the very last index that should be the greatest number out of all 6 in the array, since the array size does not grow or shrink. I was also thinking about implementing bubble sort but am a bit stuck on trying to modify a bubble sort I previously used to push registers into an array size of 6 as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Code to both my function file and sorting algorithm from a previous project will be below:

Function asm file:

```
; Data
section     .data
extern  printMSG
extern  printEndl
extern  printReg
extern  printRAX
extern  exitNormal
extern  getRand

; Code 
section     .text


;-----------------------------------------
; declare functions
global mulby4
global printXtimes  
global getRandNum
global getMax


;-----------------------------------------
; the first 6 parameters are in this order
;-----------------------------------------
;param  64bit   32bit   16bit   8bit
;1      rdi     edi     di      dil
;2      rsi     esi     si      sil
;3      rdx     edx     dx      dl
;4      rcx     ecx     cx      cl
;5      r8      r8d     r8w     r8b
;6      r9      r9d     r8w     r8b
;-----------------------------------------

;-----------------------------------------
; return valuesare in
;       rax     eax     ax      al
;-----------------------------------------


;-----------------------------------------
; the callee must preserve these registers 
;-----------------------------------------
;   rbx rbp r12 r13 r14 r15 
; 
;   The stack must be cleared

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; getMax 
; description:      returns a the largest number passed into the function 
;
; precondition:     rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 and r9 have numbers in them
;
; postcondition:    rax has the largest value passed in above
;           
;
; return            rax has the largest value passed in above
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
getMax:
    
push rdi
push rsi
push rdx
push rcx
push r8
push r9

pop r9
pop r8
pop rsi
pop rdx
pop rcx
pop rsi
pop rdi

ret
```

Sorting algorithm from prev project:

```
; =============== Start of Sorting Array / String ==============


    mov rcx, 0x5
    dec rcx

    outerloop:
    mov esi, 0    ; si is the index of array 'reverse'
    mov rdx, rcx ; rdx is the counter for innerloop
    innerloop:
    mov ah, reverse[esi]   ; assign the number reverse[si] into register 'ah'
    mov al, reverse[esi+1] ; assign the next number reverse[si+1] into 'al'
    cmp ah, al             ; Compare rev[si] and rev[si+1]
    jc carry               ; if al > ah -> Carry Flag = 1, then jump to carry
    mov reverse[esi], al   ; else, do switching btwn rev[si] and rev[si+1]
    mov reverse[esi+1], ah
    carry:
    inc esi
    dec rdx
    jnz innerloop
    loop outerloop

    mov rsi, second
    mov rdx, 0x4

    call printByteArray
    call printEndl

    mov rsi, reverse ; array name
    mov rdx, 0x5 ; Array Size of 5 in hex
    call printByteArray
    call printEndl

    ; =============== Start of Ending Array / String ==============
```

Comment: Finding the max only takes one pass, like the inner loop of a Selection Sort.  No need to repeat it to actually sort the whole array.  Also, your sort routine only sorts 8-bit integers, and for some reason uses 32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode??  Also, all your functions seem to `push rdi` / `pop rdi` for no reason (it's not being modified, and you're allowed to clobber it if you want), but yet they destroy other registers like RBX which is supposed to be call-preserved.  I also don't understand why you're repeating `rdrand % n` 10 times and taking the last one.  Just do it once.

Comment: You should remove unrelated code from your question.  I'm glad you figured out how to write `mulby4` and `printXtimes`, but that's just clutter in a huge code block for this question.

Comment: @PeterCordes You have some solid points! I think what I am mainly stuck on is, do I actually need to create a whole new array instance with 6 bytes and stores all the register values in there then run the innerloop or can I just compare all 6 registers separately somehow and update the rax variable accordingly?

Comment: You don't *need* to make an array (by `push rdi`  / `push rsi` / etc.), but that would let you use a loop.  More efficiently just do stuff like `cmp rdi, rsi` / `cmovl rdi, rsi`  (C equivalent `RDI = (RDI<RSI) ? RSI : RDI`) to reduce a pair down to the max of each pair, until you're left with one register.  (cmp/cmov, is a building block for a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network, if you did want to build a whole sort this way. Or SSE4 `pmaxsd` / `pminsd` for 32-bit integers in XMM registers.)

Comment: You've removed it now, but I think your random number generating function was using (unsigned) `div`, in which case you'd want to use unsigned compare conditions like `a` (above) or `b` (below) instead of Less or Greater.  In that case, see also [Best assembly or compilation for minimum of three values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18306615) for a bithack, but I think cmp/cmov is still faster.

Comment: Note that `rdrand` is an *exceptionally* expensive instruction; on many CPUs it has a latency of several thousand clock cycles.  If you don't need truly random numbers, you may want to call a library `rand` function instead, or write your own simple PRNG.  In any case you certainly don't want to execute `rdrand` more times than  absolutely necessary.